# Latency in poll() execution

Tags: linux, real-time, epoll

My question is regarding the poll method when executed with 0 timeout. I see that in kernels prior to 3.8, the method set TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE before attempting the descriptor call-back and in kernels after 3.8, if called with a timeout of 0 the call-back is executed and TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE is not set, as the method breaks out earlier.

Does that mean that polling can be used in low-latency applications, e.g. if one has a process dedicated to a CPU. Can the poll be interrupted even if it does not set TASK_INTERRUPTABLE?

Comment: Actually the main source of latency is single ioread32() that I perform to load a value from i/o memory. In 100000 cycles, most ioreads take 2usec but 650 take 15msec. Any clue as to why it might be taking so long?